# how to use str_replace with $row link

Tags: php, mysql

how to use str_replace with $row link
now my link is showing like this

```
example.com/view.php?category=laptop&model=dell i5
```

and i want like this

```
example.com/view.php?category=laptop&model=dell_i5
```

this is a link code

```
<a href=\"detail.php?category=" . $row['category'] . "&model=" . $row['model'] ."\" >
```

so how can i use str_replace with the link  " . $row['model'] ."

please help me to solve this issue

Complete code

```
<?php

        //connect to database

     mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
     mysql_select_db('newalldata');


$page = (empty($_GET['page'])) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];
$max_results = 6;

$from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results);



if(empty($_POST)) {
              $query = "SELECT * FROM alldata  LIMIT $from, $max_results";
} 
$result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //the main trick
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

$count=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($count%6==0)
        {
        echo "<tr/>";
        echo "<tr>";
        }


        echo "<td><hr><div class='style99' align='center'><a href=\"detail.php?category=" . $row['category'] . "&model=" . $row['model'] ."\" class=\"style2\"><img src='/media/image.php?width=200&amp;height=210&amp;image=/media/" . $row['photo'] . "'  title=". $row['price'] ."  alt=". $row['model'] ." style='FILTER: alpha(opacity=100);-moz-opacity: 1.0; opacity: 1.0;' onmouseover=BeginOpacity(this,100,40) onmouseout=EndOpacity(this,100)></a><p><font   color='#3366FF'>" . $row['category'] . "</font></p><p><font   color='#3366FF'>" . $row['model'] . "</font></p><p><font   color='#336600'>" . $row['price'] . "</font></p><div></td>";

        $count++;


}




?>
```

Comment: a simple search on google would have got you this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Better is to use `urlencode` and `urldecode` for URLs.

Comment: Bart Friederichs please tell me how can i fix with urldecode

Comment: @user1796164 read the docs before asking these questions. They are there for a reason. If you would have red the docs in the first place you wouldn't had to ask the questions

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = str_replace(" ","_",$row['model']);

<a href=\"detail.php?category=" . $row['category'] . "&model=" . $var ."\" >;
```

should do it
You may check http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php
The first parameter is what you search ( in this case the " ") , the second is what u want to heave instead ("_") and then which string is checked.

Comment: i paste here $from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results);
$var = str_raplce(" ","_",$row['model']) butnot working it is showing error on this line Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) online this   if(empty($_POST)) {

Comment: 1. You (both) misspell `str_replace`. 2. You didn't add a semicolon (`;`) after the call.

Comment: mea culpa, i fixed it.

Comment: i change my code but now no error found but problem is "&model=" . $var ."\" >; this is not working and no link show only working category example it is showing like this now example.com/view.php?category=laptop